# Hashing multiple values to a key in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, hashmap, key-value

I'm reading in a file of words and need to hash words to a key if they are anagrams. So if I read in dog, I sort the word to become dgo. And this would be my key. So I read in the word god, it would be sorted to dgo as well and they should both hash to the same key.

Here is what I am trying but I am not sure if I am doing this correctly.

```
    if(exists $hash{$string})
    {
            @values2 = $hash{$string};
            push @values2, $original; 

            for my $word (@values2)
            {
                print $word."\n";
            }
            #print "Hello";
    } 

    else
    {
         @values = ();
        $hash {$string} = @values;  
        push @values, $string; 
    }   
}
```

So the `$string` is my sorted word, the key. So if the key doesn't exist, i create a new array at that key for my $hash. i then push the orginal word into the array. But if the key already exists, I then get the array from the hash and push or add the next word.

But this isn't working properly. Can I not do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic Perl data structures are about single values. The variable `$foo` can only store a single value. The array `@foo` can store an array of *single* values. The hash `%foo` has a key that points to a *single* value.

If you need more (such as a key that points to multiple values), you need to know about [Perl References](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html). A Perl reference is a Perl data structure (such as a hash or array) where each entry points not to a single value, but to another structure.

In your case, you'd like your key (the word `dgo`) to point to an *array* of words that have those letters.

Imagine something like this:

```
my @dgo_words = qw(dog dgo god gdo odg ogd);   # All possible combinations
$words{dgo} = \@dgo_words;   # The '\' means this is a reference to @dgo_words
```

Now, `words{dgo}` points to a *reference* to the array `@dgo_words`. If *dereference* the reference (by putting the correct prefix on the variable), I can get back to the array:

```
my @array_of_dgo_words = @{ $words{dgo} };
```

Remember, `$words{dgo}` points to an array, and putting the `@` in front gives me access to that array. The curly braces in this particular case are optional:

```
my @array_of_dgo_words = @$words{dgo};
```

Personally, I prefer the braces because it highlights the fact this is a reference. Others feel that eliminating them makes the code easier to read.

If `@{ $words{dgo} }` is my array, I could use `push` to add words to the array:

```
push @{ $words{dgo} }, 'dog';
```

Now, `dog` is added to the array referenced by `$words{dgo}`.

Here's a simple program:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);


my %words;
#
# First add all the words into the correct key
#
while ( my $word = <DATA> ) {
    chomp $word;
    my $key = join '', sort split //, $word;
    push @{ $words{$key} }, $word;
}

for my $group ( sort keys %words ) {        # For each key in my word hash
    my @word_group = @{ $words{$group} };   # Dereference to get the list of words
    say qq(Words for group "'$group":);
    for my $word ( @word_group ) {          # This loop prints out the words
        say "    $word";
    }
}

__DATA__
dog
bog
save
god
gob
vase
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing you need to understand is: There is no such thing as a two dimensional data structure in perl. You don't have a hash of arrays, you have a hash of array *references*.

This can lead to some pretty subtle gotchas.

This for example - isn't doing what you think:

```
@values = ();
$hash{$string} = @values;
push @values, $string;
```

It's emptying `@values`.  But then it's *assigning* it in a scalar context. Which means you're setting:

```
$hash{$string} = 0;
```

And then inserting `$string` into`@values`, but that's making *no* difference to the hash, because you've set the hash value to the size of your empty array.

Likewise this:

```
@values2 = $hash{$string};
push @values2, $original;

for my $word (@values2) {
    print $word. "\n";
}
```

You're only *ever* going to be retrieving an array reference at best (but if you've populated with the `else` block it's not even that - it's just `0`) which means your for loop isn't going to work. `$hash{$key}` can only ever be a single value.

If you want to *set* a hash key to an array;

```
 $hash{$string} = [@values];
```

If you want to *add* elements:

```
 push ( @{$hash{$string}}, @values );
```

And if you want to extract elements;

```
my @array = @{ $hash{$string} };
```

You need the extra sigil, because that's how you tell perl 'work with a reference'. ( You can also use `->` notation in some circumstances. I've omitted this to avoid confusing the issue )

Comment: Thanks @Sobrique. This definitely helps me understand it better. So all i needed to do was to give the reference of the array, which makes sense. But I'm going to do it this way as well for extra practice. Thanks!

Comment: I wish people would stop claiming that Perl doesn't support *proper* multidimensional arrays. It absolutely does: it implements them as arrays of array references. C does it by fixing the size of rows at compile time and doing arithmetic on the indices. If anyone can propose a test for multidimensional arrays that Perl fails then I will take it back. Along with *Perl code is ugly* this is a lie that particularly riles me, and to find it being repeated by a Perl proponent is dismaying.

Comment: I don't think I said that. It certainly wasn't my intent. Merely to clarify the mechanism by which multidimensional structures are implemented. I also agree - lots of people say perl is 'messy' - it's true it lets you get away with more, but you can write bad code in any language.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. But you cannot store an array in a hash, you have to store a reference to it.

```
push @{ $hash{$string} }, $original;
```

To retrieve the array, derefence the value:

```
print join ' ', @{ $hash{dgo} }; # dog god
```

Comment: OK, I tried that but it doesn't seem to work. When i do push @{$hash{$string}}, $original; It seems to be hashing everything to the same thing. Because when I do the print that you mentioned, it prints the all the words. Like I pretty much took out everything in my if and added the line you mentioned. Or is that wrong? thanks